# Exact Negative Binomial Test with edgeR

Tags: count-data, biostatistics, group-differences

I have to select genes differentialy expressed by using the library edgeR of R. My problem is that the function ExactTest tests for differential expression between two groups of count libraries. It implements the exact test proposed by Robinson and Smyth (2008) for a difference in mean between two groups of negative binomial random variables, but I have to compare three groups! I would like to apply the test manually but, only reading the paper of Robinson and Smith, I am not able to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You seriously need to study:

> https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/edgeR/inst/doc/edgeRUsersGuide.pdf

I believe we can do the exact test by pairwise for your three groups. This is section 2.9.

However, I always use the GLM approach. The documentation has an example for you on page 20.

```
> group <- factor(c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
> design <- model.matrix(~group)
> fit <- glmFit(y, design)
```

If you have further questions on edgeR, you may want to ask on the Bioconductor support forum. Professor Gordon Smyth who wrote the edgeR package is a moderator there. There is nothing about edgeR he can't answer.